# Make google script run whenever a new Google Forms response is detected in the Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a google sheet script that returns a `ScriptFunction` for each `Response` that is added from google forms. I would like the script to run automatically when a new response is added in the sheet, so that I do not have to run it on my own whenever I want new responses to have a `ScriptFunction` result. How can I do that?

[image: The desired behaviour bellow:]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [installable onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and see if that helps?